# How to assert sinon .stub called

Tags: unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

So I have the following AWS call I am mocking out

```
    const db = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    await db.get({
           TableName: myTable,
           Key: { 'id': id }
          }).promise();
```

with the mock being:

```
        MockAws = {
        DynamoDB: {
            DocumentClient: class {
                get = sinon.stub().returns({promise: async () => (awsDynamoRespose)})
                }
            }
        }

    lambda = proxyquire('../src/handler', {
        'aws-sdk' : MockAws
    });
```

So this works, I see it returning my object, and the code can be tested.  However, since the code under test doesn't return anything, I have to assert by the mocked calls, which when I try to assert, get is undefined.

```
   console.log(MockAws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.get)  //returns undefined
   sinon.assert.calledOnce(MockAws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.get)  //returns fake is not a spy
```

I have to be close here.  How can the method be returning an object, but yet then be undefined?  DocumentClient does exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue my streak of finding an answering only after posting....

```
let awsMockGet

//inside before each
awsMockGet =  sinon.stub().returns({promise: async () => (awsDynamoRespose)})

        MockAws = {
            DynamoDB: {
                DocumentClient: class {
                    get = awsMockGet
                    }
                }
            }
```

in test

```
sinon.assert.calledOnce(awsMockGet)
```